# Unable to use fabric8 with docker for windows

Tags: windows, maven, docker, localhost, fabric8

Seems like there might be something I don't understand.

I configured my pom.xml with

```
<dockerHost>tcp://localhost:2375</dockerHost>
```

Everything is ok for build / deploy.

But it seems fabric8 plugin (v3.5.31) is not configurable with docker for windows: https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows
so it is impossible to use `fabric8:start`

Tried DOCKER_HOST env, no go.

Am I missing something? Do I really need to install with gofabric8? (which does not work anyway)
The docker engine is all there, I am unable to find any documentation on this sadly. There should be a way to configure it to use the parameter!

Thanks.

Comment: docker for windows, using Hyper-V or VirtualBox? (https://github.com/fabric8io/gofabric8/issues/229)

Comment: If I correctly remember the connection to the docker host is not via http ...`tcp://locahost:2375` ?

Comment: Yes my bad its tcp://locahost:2375

Comment: Docker for Windows uses Hyper-V and it seems to conflicts with every other virtual software like virtualbox, vmware, etc

Answer (score 1):

The dockerHost in the case for windows is not `http://localhost:2375`. You need to find the IP of the VM were docker is running. This can be found by running the command `docker-machine env <machine-name>`. This will give you the correct `DOCKER_HOST` that needs to be used.

Alternatively, there is a feature for windows in this plugin that allows you to not specify a dockerHost and rather locate a docker-machine or create a new one, and use the docker server running on that machine. Take a look at this [pull request for more info](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/pull/481)

Comment: I edited my post. Note: the build works perfectly with this adress: tcp://localhost:2375